# How can I iterate recursively though a sharepoint list using webservices?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

in sharepoint webservices, I can use getListItems() to obtain the child elements of a list.

In a document library, sometimes the element is a folder.

```
"ows_FSObjType = 1"
```

Is there any way to ask SP for the child elements of this folder?

Querying with getListItems() using the folder ID gives me a SOAP Exception.

Edit:

I found that this webservice has got more method

[Site Data Webservice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774720.aspx)

There is an "enumerate folder" method, which has got a "isFolder" property, but no method to recurse its contents.

Thank you, Sam. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the GetListItems method, one of the optional parameters is an XMLNode called "QueryOptions".  One of the elements you can put in that node is `<Folder>`.

So you should be able to pass in something like:

```
<QueryOptions>
    <Folder>/My/Path/Here</Folder>
</QueryOptions>
```

I may be off a bit syntatically (didn't try to build and run a query when making this post), but the general idea should be sound.  You can see more details on this in the [MSDN GetListItems Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx).