# WSS GetListItems Not Returning Folders without Inherited Permissions when Calling with GUID

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss, wss-3.0, caml

WSS 3.0 List Service

I am running **GetListItems()** on a Picture Library (name Pictures) using the follow CAML query:

```
<Query>
</Query>
<ViewFields>
  <FieldRef Name="EncodedAbsUrl"/>
  <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
  <FieldRef Name="ContentType"/>
</ViewFields>
<QueryOptions>
  <Folder>Pictures\Uploads</Folder>
  <ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll"/>
</QueryOptions>
```

This query correctly returns all files and folders in the Uploads folder.

However, if I navigate to the Uploads folder and select **Edit Permissions** on the Uploads folder then select **Actions** > **Edit Permissions** and then click **OK** on the confirmation box this query no longer works.

I do not believe this is related to permissions, because I did not modify the permissions at all I just “cop[ied] permissions from parent, and then stop[ped] inheriting permissions,” by selecting **Edit Permissions**. In addition, *I do not receive an error message when running this query,* I just get an empty result set.

Other things I have tried:

- Removing all tags in QueryOptions: This still does not return the Uploads folder or any file or folder under it
- Adding permissions directly to the folder for my user account: This does not help
- Searching for something with a similar problem or some sort of solution: No avail

Other information:

- Calling this from C# Win Form App

Does anyone know how to fix or work around this? If more detail or clarification is necessary please let me know.

So after some more experimenting, a solution was found, though not well explained or documented. The problem was related to how the **GetListItems** function was being called, here is the code that was not working correctly:

```
System.Xml.XmlNode ndListView = listProxy.GetListAndView("Pictures", "");
string strListID = ndListView.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["Name"].Value;
XmlNode returnNode = listProxy.GetListItems(strListID, strViewID, queryNode, viewNode, _maxFolders, optionNode, null);
```

This was not working as expected for the situation explained above, however, it was working for every other folder and file. The solution was to send **GetListItems** the list name, "Pictures" instead of the list GUID, like so:

```
XmlNode returnNode = listProxy.GetListItems("Pictures", strViewID, queryNode, viewNode, _maxFolders, optionNode, null);
```

**Update**
Furthermore, MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx) recommends the usage of GUID instead of the list name when using the Lists.GetListItem method:

> *listName*: A string that contains either
>   the display name or the GUID for the
>   list. It is recommended that you use
>   the GUID, which must be surrounded by
>   curly braces ({}). When querying the
>   UserInfo table, the string contains
>   "UserInfo".

I do not know why this code works and the original does not. Although my problem has been solved, does anyone have a clue why my original code does not work (only for the situation explained above) and the modified code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some more experimenting, a solution was found, though not well explained or documented. The problem was related to how the **GetListItems** function was being called, here is the code that was not working correctly:

```
System.Xml.XmlNode ndListView = listProxy.GetListAndView("Pictures", "");
string strListID = ndListView.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["Name"].Value;
XmlNode returnNode = listProxy.GetListItems(strListID, strViewID, queryNode, viewNode, _maxFolders, optionNode, null);
```

This was not working as expected for the situation explained above, however, it was working for every other folder and file. The solution was to send **GetListItems** the list name, "Pictures" instead of the list GUID, like so:

```
XmlNode returnNode = listProxy.GetListItems("Pictures", strViewID, queryNode, viewNode, _maxFolders, optionNode, null);
```