# Getting a list of documents in specific directory on a MOSS Server using C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, sharepoint-2007

Me and my partner have to develop a system to upload and manage files on a Sharepoint Server.
To do this we have to create an application that can accsess a specific directory/file library on the Server (where the documents will be stored) to do this we want to use the method using SOAP (Web Service Method). My partner has already started with the project and got the Server to respond but it just doesn't seem like the right/easiest way to do, also I'm not really a big help since i have no experience with Sharepoint and Web Services especially SOAP.
What I know so far is basically only how i can access the _vti_bin with the WebServices list and that's pretty much it I've checked multiple projects that other people did but most of them are using the Sharepoint.Client.dll reference which isn't available for us.

Problems that we have encountered:
Access denied for user Anonymous.
No Access to the Client.dll and other DLLs stored on the Server.

We have:
**no** access to the Server
Visual Studio 2010
Sharepoint 2007

Help is very much appreciated and very much needed :)

Comment: FWIW have a look at the U2 CAML generator - it will help with searching through lists on your site. http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx

Comment: @nonnb thank you, I'm going to look into that.

Comment: U2 CAML is not helping the only help i got from it is that i know what my requests should return in theory but all i got from CAML is a list of folders in the main directory but i don't get any results on the sub directories

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question.

Each Site is 'separate' in Sharepoint, e.g. http://myMOSSServer/sites and http://myMOSSServer/sites/MySite1 are entirely different sites - you will need to connect to each separately.

Folders / SubFolders in a document list are mostly for the benefit of the UI - internally they are stored in a flat structure.

See [CAML query that includes folders in result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557675/caml-query-that-includes-folders-in-result-set) for an idea of how to filter folders etc

Be careful of this - don't put the  into SPQuery:
http://moldenco.blogspot.com/2006/11/using-caml-to-filter-infopath-published.html